# Sort array with range of values in O(n)

Tags: algorithm

There's an array `A[1, ..., n]`, and its known that every `1 <= l <= n` then `A[l] in {1,2,...,n^5}`.

How can I find an algroithm which sorts this in O(n) ?

Comment: n-bucket radix sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine representing the values in `A[i]` in Base-n system. Then each number becomes a five-digit n-ary number, meaning that you can sort the entire array with five applications of [*Radix Sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort), with "radix" of n.

Compute the value of each "digit" x in a number k as follows:

d<sub>x</sub> = (k / (n <sup>x</sup>)) % n

where `/` denotes integer division.

Answer (score 1):

sort list of integers a using base-N radix sort,
also this applies for a simple list

```
def rsort(a,N):

if a:
    bins = [ [],[],[],[],[] ]

    m = max(a)
    r = 1

    while m > r:
        for e in a:
            bins[(e/r)%N].append(e)

        r = r * N
        a = []
        for i in range(N):
            a.extend(bins[i])
            bins[i] = []

return a
```